# Flatten multidimensional array not working

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge

I have two arrays like the following.

```
$alerts_array=array(1) {
          [0]=> array(11) {
                           ["CustomAlertsID"]=> int(3) 
                           ["CustomAlerts_Name"]=> string(10) "title demo" 
                           ["CustomAlerts_PublishDate"]=> string(10) "2016-07-03" 
                           ["CustomAlerts_ExpiryDate"]=> string(10) "2016-07-21"
                          }
            }
  $singlebtn_array  =array(3) {
       ["button_text0"]=> string(16) "Button Name1only"
       ["button_text1"]=> string(12) "button name2" 
       ["button_text2"]=> string(16) "button name3_new" 
     }
```

I have merged the two arrays into a single multidimensional array which looks like following

```
$alerts_array = array_merge($alerts_array,$singlebtn_array);

array(4) { [0]=> array(11) 
               { ["CustomAlertsID"]=> int(3)
                 ["CustomAlerts_Name"]=> string(10) "title demo"   
                 ["CustomAlerts_PublishDate"]=> string(10) "2016-07-03" 
                 ["CustomAlerts_ExpiryDate"]=> string(10) "2016-07-21" 
               } 

           [1]=> array(1) 
                 { ["button_text0"]=> string(16) "Button Name1only" }
           [2]=> array(1) 
                 { ["button_text1"]=> string(12) "button name2" } 
           [3]=> array(1) { ["button_text2"]=> string(16) "button name3_new" } }
```

I need both keys and values in the new flattened array

I need it like this:

```
array(4) { [0]=> array(11) 
  { ["CustomAlertsID"]=> int(3)
    ["CustomAlerts_Name"]=> string(10) "title demo"   
    ["CustomAlerts_PublishDate"]=> string(10) "2016-07-03" 
    ["CustomAlerts_ExpiryDate"]=> string(10) "2016-07-21"  
    ["button_text0"]=> string(16) "Button Name1only"
    ["button_text1"]=> string(12) "button name2" 
    ["button_text2"]=> string(16) "button name3_new" }}
```

I have usedthe following code for combining.

```
 $newArr = array();
 foreach ($alerts_array as $key=>$tmp) {
    $newArr = array_merge($newArr, array_values($tmp));
 }
```

The `$newArr` is giving me the result ,but keys are lost

Answer (score 1):

Simply merge the first key `[0]` of your `$alerts_array`, like this:

```
$alerts_array = array_merge($alerts_array[0], $singlebtn_array);
```

That will output:

```
array(7) {
  ["CustomAlertsID"]=>
  int(3)
  ["CustomAlerts_Name"]=>
  string(10) "title demo"
  ["CustomAlerts_PublishDate"]=>
  string(10) "2016-07-03"
  ["CustomAlerts_ExpiryDate"]=>
  string(10) "2016-07-21"
  ["button_text0"]=>
  string(16) "Button Name1only"
  ["button_text1"]=>
  string(12) "button name2"
  ["button_text2"]=>
  string(16) "button name3_new"
}
```

Also see the working demo [here](https://3v4l.org/176Ld).

Comment: Then please show some relevant examples/parts of your code. This does exactly what your question states.

Comment: The result is like this: { ["CustomAlertsID"]=> int(3) ["CustomAlerts_Name"]=> string(10) "title demo" 
" ["CustomAlerts_PublishDate"]=> string(10) "2016-07-03" ["CustomAlerts_ExpiryDate"]=> string(10) "2016-07-21"   [0]=> array(1) { ["button_text0"]=> string(16) "Button Name1only" } [1]=> array(1) { ["button_text1"]=> string(12) "button name2" } [2]=> array(1) { ["button_text2"]=> string(16) "button name3_new" } }

Comment: Its working in https://3v4l.org/AfRQW.Its giving me the above output in my browser.

Comment: How did you convert $alerts_array to the format in the above link https://3v4l.org/AfRQW

Answer (score 0):

To get what you want because alerts is an array of arrays:

```
$alerts_array = array_merge($alerts_array[0],$singlebtn_array);
```

But with an array of arrays you will probably want a loop. Not sure if each one would be the same thing or if you will have multiples but this will help you.

```
$alerts_array; //Your array for arrays
singlebtn_array; //Whatever this is
$flattened_alerts_singlebtn = array();    

foreach($alerts_array as $alert_array){
    //This will be every array in the alerts as your flattened
    //array with the singlebtn
    $flattened_alerts_singlebt[] = array_merge($alert_array,$singlebtn_array); 
}
```

You can then loop `$flattened_alerts_singlebtn` to get each falttened array that could exist.